# Why is deleting files so slow on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, performance

Why is deleting files on Windows Vista so slow even with small files?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Vista, did you install any service packs yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously **recycling** files. That means: Windows **moves** them into the "trash" folder.

To delete a file, go to the Explorer, select the file(s), hit `Shift-Del`, and Windows will really **delete** them.

Alternatively, you could [**disable the trash folder**](http://www.real-knowledge.com/permanently-delete-vista-recycle-bin-files.htm) (also called Recycle Bin).

Note: This will permanently delete files, you will no longer be able to recover deleted files from the Recycle Bin.

Comment: really good point, in this case there's something to do with the slow copy. I'll test it!!

Comment: Additionally, I should mention, that in general, all kinds of indexing services (Windows search, Google desktop search (?) ) can make file operations slower.

Comment: Indeed it's faster when you Shift-Delete my files!

Answer (score 0):

If there is another disk-intensive operation going on, Explorer can be preempted. Check your Resource Monitor to see what other processes are heavily accessing the disk.

Comment: Yes, I'll check it on Resource Monitor to see what's going on. Perhaps Google Desktop??! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

google desktop = slow file operations. Put up your resource monitor and try it. I did and removed google because the hit was sometimes up to 30%.  Windows normally will wait for slow cpu usage before rebuilding the index, google wants it all now.

Comment: Google Desktop here is taking 16 threads, average CPU is below 1.0. But I think Google Desktop interfears when you delete a file, since it's configured to delete it also from index. I uninstall it for testing purposes.